# $content variable in block.tpl.php

Tags: blocks

I have customized a `block.tpl.php` file and I want to access the individual fields in it. But when I put `print render($content['field_name'])` in my code nothing is printed out. And also `print_r(array_keys($content))` doesn't give anything.

I have used the above codes in my `page.tpl` and `node.tpl` files successfully before.

I'm on D7.

So is it done somehow differently in block template? What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the code for the original [block.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.tpl.php/7) file, `$content` doesn't actually get run through `render()`, as it's already been rendered to a string.

If you want to alter the block content while it's still in a structured array you should use a [`hook_block_view_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7) implementation in a custom module. This is the example from the docs page:

```
function hook_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  // Remove the contextual links on all blocks that provide them.
  if (is_array($data['content']) && isset($data['content']['#contextual_links'])) {
    unset($data['content']['#contextual_links']);
  }
  // Add a theme wrapper function defined by the current module to all blocks
  // provided by the "somemodule" module.
  if (is_array($data['content']) && $block->module == 'somemodule') {
    $data['content']['#theme_wrappers'][] = 'mymodule_special_block';
  }
}
```

How successful you'll be using this method depends on how well the modules that provide the blocks respect render arrays. If an implementation of `hook_block()` by a particular module flattens the block content to a string before it is made alterable, then you'll have to make the changes somewhere else in the process (probably using a theme preprocess/override).

Comment: I've created my block through Views. Should I follow your instructions regardless?

Comment: Blocks created with views will also go through `hook_block_view_alter()` so yes, this is still an option. You could also look at overriding the template file for that particular block if the block alter doesn't work